# Проверка на нажатие кнопки js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. У меня есть функция, которая создает div и возле div создает кнопку удалить. Соответственно я могу создать любое кол-во div. Вопрос когда удаляю при нажатии кнопки buttonDel, как найти какой именно был удален div, чтоб из него взять информацию.

```
    function pic1(personToRender) {
      const element = document.body;
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const buttonDel=document.createElement('button');
      buttonDel.append(document.createTextNode('X'));
      buttonDel.onclick = function () {
        div.remove();
      }
      const newTextNode = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(personToRender));
      div.append(newTextNode,buttonDel);
      element.append(div);
    }
```

Comment: `как найти какой именно` - какой?

Comment: `buttonDel.onclick=function () { console.log(this.closest('div').innerHTML); div.remove(); }`

Comment: Желательно приводить полный пример. Не только кусок JS-кода, но и соответствующий html.

Comment: @ksa Зачем здесь html ?)

Comment: @Rudi, для полного ответа. Поскольку твое предложение вешать обработчики на каждую кнопку я считаю не особо путевым решением.

Comment: @ksa У тебя с семантическими связями проблемы. Я предложил closest('div') чтобы ТС мог "из него взять информацию". Эта функция просто вставляет в body и вся её структура принадлежит автору, не мне. Не путёвый это твой совет привести html там где он не нужен вообще. И советы по mongo.. Я говорит синтаксис не знаю но попробуй так))